# long boot times of Google Compute Engine windows instances when using custom disk images

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, boot

I've configured a windows machine with all the tools and scripts that I'll need. Some of the script are places in shell:startup folder. I then created disk image and use it to replicate instance.

There are 2 things that alarm me:

1. Instances that are using a disk image from the original take longer
   to boot.
2. Process that I start at login, is taking as much as 4x times longer
   to start, than if I run it interactively (by clicking with mouse).

Is it expected that instances using custom disk images take longer to boot? What can I do trim the boot time in general?

Thanks for any advice. I am coming from unix systems and windows is a total black box to me.

Comment: Do any of the scripts reference network locations?

Comment: Not sure by what you mean by referencing network locations. I start apache, curl to the master that instance is running and start the main process I launched the instance for. There are some HTTP requests during process execution.